# Accessing optional arguments in C, with two arguments in one

Tags: c, shell, args

I need access to `[pid[value]]`, but I'm not sure what the notation even means.

I know how to use `**args` to get arguments given to my program. If I have `[pid][value]`, I can do `args[1]` for `pid` and `args[2]` for `value`, but if I have `[pid[value]]`, I don't know. How do I access both arguments?

Comment: You have to be a little more specific, what do you mean with two arguments in one? How are you passing them from the commandline?

Comment: Can you give an example of your use-case? What are `pid` and `value` and what exactly you want to do with `[pid][value]` ?

Comment: Implement priority in C, using getpriority and setpriority, and i need to do priority [pid [value] ] pid is getpid() and value the new priority for the current pid

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Optional arguments only make sense when you have sensible defaults. Assuming you do, decide which one is most often required and make it the first one.

```
char *pid ;
char *value ;

if (argc < 1) {
    value = VALUE_DEFAULT ;
    pid = PID_DEFAULT ;
    }
else if (argc < 2) {
    value = VALUE_DEFAULT ;
    pid = argv[1] ;
    }
else if (argc < 3) {
    value = argv[1] ;
    pid = argv[2] ;
    }
```

Having positional optional parameters really only works if you have a very restricted set of parameters (which you do) or you use it so often typing in flags or parameter names is never worth the bother.

It's a good idea to be fluent in command line parsing. It's one thing that's not going to change much in the future.

Answer (score 1):

That notation typically means that `pid` and `value` are both optional arguments, and further `value` is only allowed if `pid` is first specified. So your program can be called with zero arguments, one argument (so `args[1]` is the PID), or two arguments (`args[1]` is still the PID, and `args[2]` is the new priority.